# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\{|x| >n\}} X \,dP =0 $ By using Beppo Levi's Lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \int\limits_{\{|x| >n\}} X \,dP =0  $$

Let $X$ be a random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathbf{F},P ),$ if $ E|X|<+\infty $

I have started to learn some probability theorem and I'm struggling with this exercise.

Comment: What is $f$? Is it a function?

Comment: sorry I have edited the question

Comment: **Hint** Use Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Since $X\in L_1$, $X_+$ and $X_-$ are also in $L_1$. Write $\int X_+\,dP=\sum_{n\geq1}\int_{\{n-1 <X_+\leq n\}}X_+\,dP$  and $\int X_-\,dP=\sum_{n\geq1}\int_{\{n-1<X_-\leq n\}}X_-\,dP$.  Apply Beppo-Levi to each and you get what you want. Recall that BL states that if $f_n:\omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is a sequence of measurable functions then $\sum_n\int f_n=\int\sum_nf_n$.

Answer (score 2):

You might use the dominated convergence theorem:
$$|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>n\}}X | \leq |X| $$
and $\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>n\}}$ goes to $0$ a.s.

If you want to use Beppo Levi's theorem just observe that $\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>n\}}$ decreases to zero.

Remark: since $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<+\infty$ we have that $|X|<+\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Doesn't Beppo Levi need a sequence of nonnegative functions? In this case it cannot be applied directly

Comment: This is not an application of Beppo-Levi as the OP asked. Otherwise this question is a duplicate and should be closed. Recall Beppo-Levy states that Recall that BL states that if $f_n:\omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is a sequence of measurable functions then $\sum_n\int f_n=\int\sum_nf_n$.